# javascript function returning result form mysql query as array

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am new in node, I wanna return result from mysql query as array.

Here my code :

```
function alterObject(obj) {

  var c = [];
  con.query("SELECT KeyName FROM SearchKeyWord", function(err, rows, field) {
    for (var i in rows) {
      c = c + rows[i].KeyName + "'" + "," + "'";
    }
    c = c.substring(0, c.length - 2);
    console.log(c)
  });

  obj.foo = c;

}

alterObject(myObj);

console.log(myObj.foo);
```

Comment: When you ask question you should tell what your actual problem is, what you expect the result should be and what you actually get.

Comment: `query` as many functions in nodejs, is an asynchronous function. The callback you pass to asynchronous functions is called when the result is ready and will always be called, after the current _code flow_  is finished, so at the time you do `obj.foo = c;` or `console.log(myObj.foo);` the callback was not called.

Comment: Another related duplicate [Why is my variable unaltered after I modify it inside of a function? - Asynchronous code reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23667086)